# Blending with background in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, blending

I am new to blending in cocos2d-x and couldn't find much on google.

I have white background in my game and i have added red colour sprite "circle.png" on it(empty from centre region) .

Now i want to blend certain parts of circle with background so that it seems to user that the circle is broken from certain parts.

Comment: varun, your question is not sufficient enough ? add some photos to better communicate your question like, circle sprite and desired blending (photoshopped or something).

Comment: also, check out setBlendFunc() from cocos2d-x api, that will help .. also there will be test-cpp in your cocos2d-x folder, it would have all sample code you will need.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
i have uploaded image on http://i58.tinypic.com/23w8zsi.jpg  

Hope it helps

I used setBlendFunc() but couldn't understand whether to use GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA or GL_ZERO or any other.

Comment: There are some macros that help you set BlendFunc::ADDITIVE (Enables Additive blending) which uses {GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE}. url : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.5/d3/d14/structcocos2d_1_1_blend_func.html